# XML data to array

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, linq

Below is the XML data I am getting from a URL. When I view source, here is how it looks:

```
<xml>
    <beginning>

        <id>information from rss provider here</id>
        <updated>information from rss provider here</updated>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='tttt' title='alternate'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='tttt'/>

        <someschemas>
            <id>test</id>
            <movieid>test</movieid>
            <updated>teeeeest</updated>
            <types scheme='vals' term='test'/>
            <title type='html'>test</title>
            <summary type='html'>test</summary>
            <descriptions type='html'>test</descriptions>
            <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='tttt' title='alternate'/>
            <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='tttt'/>
            <actor>
                <name>teest</name>
                <phone>test</phone>
            </actor>
        </someschemas>

        <someschemas>
            <id>test</id>
            <movieid>test</movieid>
            <updated>teeeeest</updated>
            <types scheme='vals' term='test'/>
            <title type='html'>test</title>
            <summary type='html'>test</summary>
            <descriptions type='html'>test</descriptions>
            <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='tttt' title='alternate'/>
            <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='tttt'/>
            <actor>
                <name>teest</name>
                <phone>test</phone>
            </actor>
        </someschemas>

        <someschemas>
            <id>test</id>
            <movieid>test</movieid>
            <updated>teeeeest</updated>
            <types scheme='vals' term='test'/>
            <title type='html'>test</title>
            <summary type='html'>test</summary>
            <descriptions type='html'>test</descriptions>
            <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='tttt' title='alternate'/>
            <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='tttt'/>
            <actor>
                <name>teest</name>
                <phone>test</phone>
            </actor>
        </someschemas>
    </beginning>
</xml>
```

I am able to read the content in a message box:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.test.com/file.xml");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();   
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(dataStream);                      
IEnumerable<XElement> employees = xelement.Elements();            
foreach (var employee in employees)
{
    if (employee.Elements("content") != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(employee.Value.ToString());
    }                 
}
```

I would like to save this to an array, or a list, or LINQ.

How can i use the code above with the XML above and make it into an array.

I only want all the data within `<someschemas>.` and just these values as key/value pairs:

```
<title type='html'>test</title>
    <summary type='html'>test</summary>
    <descriptions type='html'>test</descriptions>
<actor>
<name>teest</name>
<phone>test</phone>
</actor>
```

Comment: Well why don't you create an `Employee` class? You are looping through stuff already, just add it to a class, give that some semantic meaning and you are sorted. For instance, instead of *showing* `employee.Value`, *add* it to a `List`.

Comment: hi Arran, i would like the value to be in key/value pair. thanks.

Comment: Take note that `WebResponse` and `Stream` are `IDisposable` resources and therefore should be within `using` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, you need to make your own class to store each `someschemas` object.

```
class SomeSchemas
{
    public string ID {get;set;}
    public string MovieId {get;set;}
    //add in others here
    public string Actor_Name {get;set;}
    public string Actor_Phone {get;set}
}
```

Then loop through and add your items

```
List<SomeSchemas> items = XElement.Load(dataStream)
    .Descendants("someschemas")
    .Select(x => new SomeSchemas()
    {
        ID = x.Element("id").Value,
        MovieId = x.Element("movieid").Value,
        //add in others here
        Actor_Name = x.Element("actor").Element("name").Value,
        Actor_Phone = x.Element("actor").Element("phone").Value
    }.ToList();
```

If `Actors` can have more than one entry, then you need to make a `List` object inside `SomeSchemas`.

Then you can use `items` in a loop, and do linq on it. It won't be a key/value pair (like a `dictionary`), but you can select an item based on its ID, if they are unique.

```
SomeSchemas myObject = items.Single(x => x.ID == "asdf");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a LINQ to XML Version:

```
string[] names = XElement.Load(dataStream).Descendants("Name")
                        .Select(element => element.Value).ToArray();
```

This will give all the `Name` element from the document.

Comment: Good, except your call `ToArray()` when your variable is an `XElement`. Return type should be `string[]`.

Comment: i got an error that says you cannot implicitly convert type string[] to system.xml.linq.xlelement

Comment: great thanks, so now i can loop through the 'names' and access the key/value pairs?

Comment: @Menew, for that, you need to edit your post to define what your key/value pairs are. And you can use your `names` in a for/foreach loop.

Comment: @Nirmal your answer was also right, however, i needed to create a detailed key/value pair.