# Deserializing an Xml document no results

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm having some difficulties de-serializing an Xml document I have. See small complete sample of doc below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MailClient>
<Client Id="Outlook.com">
    <Property Supported="false" Category="Responsive" Name="@media"><![CDATA["@media"]]></Property>
    <Property Supported="false" Category="Selectors" Name="*"><![CDATA["*"]]></Property>
    <Property Supported="false" Category="Selectors" Name="ElementSelector"><![CDATA["E"]]></Property>
    <Property Supported="false" Category="Selectors" Name="[=]"><![CDATA["[=]"]]></Property>
    <Property Supported="false" Category="Selectors" Name="[~=]"><![CDATA["[~=]"]]></Property>
    <Property Supported="false" Category="Selectors" Name="[^=]"><![CDATA["[^=]"]]></Property>
    <Property Supported="false" Category="Selectors" Name="[$=]"><![CDATA["[$=]"]]></Property>
    <Property Supported="false" Category="Selectors" Name="[*=]"><![CDATA["[*=]"]]></Property>
</Client>
</MailClient>
```

The associated classes look like this:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("Client"), XmlType("Client")]
public class MailClient
{
    [XmlElement("Client")]
    public List<CssRule> CssRules { get; set; }

    public MailClient()
    {
        CssRules = new List<CssRule>();
    }
}

[XmlType("Property")]
public class CssRule
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Supported")]
    public bool IsSupported{ get; set; }

    public CssRule(){}
}
```

And the de-serializing is done with:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MailClient));
FileStream xmlFile = new FileStream(ConfigFile, FileMode.Open);
MailClient clients = (MailClient)serializer.Deserialize(xmlFile);
```

I was getting an exception `There is an error in XML document (2, 2).` relating to the `MailClient` element: `{"<MailClient xmlns=''> was not expected."}`. So I passed in a xml root attribute:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MailClient), 
new XmlRootAttribute("MailClient"));
```

Which seemed to correct the problem. `clients` now contains a single `client` but none of the propertys have been populated, that is to say `category`, `name` etc... all remain empty.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong here? At this point I'm beginning to think it might be quicker for me to just use Linq to Xml rather than trying to de-serialize this

Comment: For something as small as this, I would vote to use `XElement` than serialization. (Look at my [last answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19096828/1043380) for some ideas).

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes that's my fallback plan but I thought this approach would be a little cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MailClient` class, you have `XmlRoot("Client")`. Change that to the actual root element name, specifically `XmlRoot("MailClient")`. That way, you don't have to use the `XmlRootAttribute` in code.

For collections, you should use the [XmlArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute.aspx) and [XmlArrayItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) attributes.

And where you are using `XmlType` attributes, you should be using [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attributes.

Comment: If i do that, i get no rules at all in `clients` - clients count is 0

Comment: Yes, sorry. My answer was incomplete at first. Please see my revisions. My point is that you're using the attributes all wrong. :)

Comment: Ahhh I see, I think the issue was that I was decorating the `List<CssRule>` as `XmlElement`, adding the attribute `XmlArray` to it seems to solve my problems. One other quick question, is it possible to map the value of the `Property` element (the element inner text) to a property on in the `CssRule` class - the same way that the attributes are mapped to properties?

Comment: nvm - seems like you just need to decorate the property with `XmlText()`. Thanks for your help :)